# Coordinates seem to show overlapping but RViz doesn't

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz

How can you place two objects that seem to overlap with their units but appear stacked on top of each other [original intent] in RViz?

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ale55LcdZeE) tutorial on ROS and URDF. I have tried to paste screenshots to clarify but feel free to watch the video if you have the time. The presenter is showing how to create a joint between `base link` and `link 01` in the first image below.

[image: plan]

Here's the `xacro` file that I am confused about. If the `xyz` coordinates of the origin of the box are `[0 0 0]` and its dimensions are `[1 1 1]`, how can the cylinder have its origin at `[0 0 0.2]`? Isn't it within the box?

[image: xacro.xml file]

I considered that the `xyz` coordinates may be relative to the link itself but where does RViz know where to place the object in the world? Moreover, the joint is placed at `[0 0 0.5]` and this makes sense. Shouldn't the origin of the cylinder have been `[0 0 1.2]`? This is how it looks like in RViz. 
[image: RViz image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin defined inside `link_01` is *not* the position of the cylinder in the global coordinate frame (the "world"), but in its own private frame. By default the object's center lies at the origin of its own coordinate frame, but in this case, the cylinder is shifted $0.2 m$ upwards along the $z$ axis, placing its bottom on the origin.

The effect of this shift is that the reference point for any further manipulations of `link_01` now lies on its bottom, instead of its center as would normally be the case.

Likewise, the origin defined in the `base_link__link_01` joint is defined relative to the coordinate frame of the parent link, in this case `base_link`. It also specifies where the *origin* frame of the child link will be placed, relative to the frame of the parent link.

All this leads to the following configuration:

[image: links and frames]

As you can see in the image above, the `base_link__link_01` joint places the origin frame of `link_01` $0.5 m$ above the origin frame of `base_link`. And since `link_01` itself is shifted relative to its own frame, the result is that the bottom of `link_01` is placed exactly on top of `base_link`.

The topic of coordinate frames, the transforms between them and their use in robotics is one of the more advanced, and unfortunately I don't know of a comprehensive reference on it, but [this tutorial](https://w3.cs.jmu.edu/spragunr/CS354_S19/handouts/frames.pdf) seems a good start point to getting acquainted with it.

Comment: You wrote, "And since `base_link` ..." but did you mean to say, "And since `link_01`..."?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Changed the answer to fix it.