# What is the purpose of an empty link without any child elements?

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, joint

I was looking at a model `xacro` [`urdf`] file in a ROS tutorial when I saw:

```
<link name="robot_footprint"></link>
```

right at the top. There were no child tags for:  `<collision>`, `<visual>` or `<inertial>`. There was however a joint right after but no further references to the `robot_footprint` link.

```
  <joint name="robot_footprint_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent link="robot_footprint"/>
    <child link="chassis" />
  </joint>
```

What does the empty link serve?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it's probably used as a projection of the robot's root link on the floor. This is often useful for motion planning or SLAM, where the robot's pose is read (or set) as the projection from that frame to the global frame. Going back to [that other case involving coordinate frames](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/20499/4310), `robot_footprint` would serve the same purpose as shifting `link_01` vertically relative to its frame.

Another common use of such links is to define sensor coordinate frames. For example, coordinates in a point cloud are often given relative to frame of the sensor that generated it; by creating a link that matches the sensor's position relative to the robot's root link, transforms can be computed to map those points to the robot's pose in the global coordinate frame.

See the [URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) for more information on how links and joints work and are used in ROS.

Comment: In the first case, what do you mean by "a projection" of the robot's link? If the robot is moving, is the location just traced based on this reference position, `robot_footprint`?

Comment: There is a sensor and motion planning/ SLAM will be dealt with next. I also observed that only the chassis has the `<pose>` tag, i.e., `<link name='chassis'>
    <pose>0 0 0.1 0 0 0</pose>`
. Why is that?

Comment: By "projection on the floor" I mean that if the `chassis` link is at position $(x, y, z)$, then `robot_footprint` is at position $(x, y, 0)$.

Comment: By default a link is assumed to be at the origin of its coordinate frame, so in that case pose information can be omitted.

Comment: Also see the [URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) for more information,